# Oracle db regexp to filter out rows that are not in a specific pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sqlplus

In an Oracle DB table, one of the column has the following `VARCHAR2` format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

I would love to filter out all rows that don't match this pattern. So, I wrote the following `regexp` in my query, but the query is returning all rows in the table including all rows that matches `2014-09-10 10:02:33` pattern.

```
SELECT COLUMN 
FROM TABLE
WHERE regexp_like(COLUMN, '^[[:digit:]{4},-,[:digit:]{2},-,[:digit:]{2}, ,[:digit:]{2},:,[:digit:]{2},:,[:digit:]{2}]');
```

What's the problem with my query?

Comment: That regex will match with every varchar that starts with a digit or , or : or - or a mustache.   So that's why you get so many rows.    
You could use this instead: `^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}$`. 
But @vkp's answer is even better because it also provides some validation on the datestamp.

Comment: What are those commas supposed to do in the search pattern?

Comment: Made a mistake, commas shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
select col
from tablename
where regexp_like(col,'^([1-9]\d{3})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$')
```

- `[1-9]\d{3}` - matches all years starting from 1000 to 9999
- `0[1-9]|1[0-2]` - matches months from 01 to 12
- `0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]` - matches days from 01 to 31
- `\s` - matches space
- `0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]` - matches hours from 00 to 23
- `[0-5][0-9]` - matches minutes from 00 to 59, seconds from 00 to 59

The query would also give you `02-30-2016` etc. as valid dates. You need to include extra logic to match months with 30 days and February based on a leap year.

It is not recommended to store `date` as `varchar`. You can write a procedure that would return only valid dates when you convert it using `to_date`.

Edit: The below query would match all the valid dates except February 29 in a leap year.

```
select col
from tablename
where regexp_like(col,'^([1-9]\d{3})-((0[13578]|10|12)-([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])|(0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)|(02-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-8])))\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$')
```

Comment: Can you explain your query?

Comment: see the explanation

Comment: It's a read only db that I didn't design. So I am not allowed to write any procedure. When I tried to convert it using to_date, it throws error because there are some rows that are in strange format. This query is the whole point of filtering those bad rows out, and then I will do a to_date in the filtered rows.